# Is it okay to load sprites in a separate class to reuse later?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna-4.0

Alright, so I have quite a few classes that use all of the same sprites (it's a GUI). I figured that rather than loading the same sprites multiple times, it would make sense to make a small, separate class for this.

Would this be a better way to do this, or unnecessary?

Comment: If it reduces repetition and makes code maintenance and extensibility easier then it is better. If not then it is just extra work, but you can do it if it makes you feel better :)

Comment: Alright. I think it will. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContentManager caches images for you, so if you only want that, is Ok only using the content manager.

If you want implement now or in next future a skin funcionality maybe convenient to make a Style class or Skin class where the sprites were related to its use. (Left Corner, Right Corner, Top Border, Scroll Bar Up, ...)